# Alllocate correct byte array size

Tags: java, sockets, networking, arrays, datagram

I am trying to connect to a socket using this code

```
public static Socket connectToSocket(String name)
    {
        try
        {
            while(true)
            {
                byte[] receiveData = new byte[name.length()];
                DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket(PORT);
                DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
                clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);

                if(Arrays.equals(name.getBytes(),receiveData))
                {
                    return new Socket(receivePacket.getAddress(),PORT);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

But my problem is i dot know what size to make my byte array for all information to be processed.  I tried just making the receiveData array an enormous size, but i realized that wouldnt work because it would mess up this statement.

```
        if(Arrays.equals(name.getBytes(),receiveData))
```

What would be the best way to deal with this issue.

Comment: just fyi, this won't compile, because there is a possibility that you don't reach a return statement.

Comment: actually it compiled just fine java doesn't check for that

Comment: You could write to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead.  Is there any way that you can handle the data while it is still incomplete?

Comment: I am iterating through all the available servers to connect to until i reach a server with the name the user specified that is the byte array i am trying to get, and then from that i am creating a socket to that server.

Comment: i like the classes i am currently using because they seem to work for my current configuration except for the problem i am experiencing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DatagramPacket contains the length of the data actually received. See the 'length()' method.

But I'm curious about this protocol. Why not just connect to the server with TCP and ask it its name? and eliminate the UDP part altogether?

Comment: because when i was using just plain tcp i couldnt seem to connect to external computers and i thought this might help, but i havent been able to test it yet, how would i use the length method of an object in that objects constructor.

Comment: 'if (name.equals(new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength())'. But UDP won't solve a TCP connectivity problem. If you can't connect, you can't connect.